# How to effectively manage a LastUpdated field with MongoDB on .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database and I am making changes to it using the `MongoDB.Driver` NuGet package. I have a `User` collection and this user collection has a `LastUpdated` field. How do I effectively update this field whenever a user's other fields change without changing all update calls in my code?

I know how to do this with EF Core. You need to override the `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync`  methods in the `DbContext` class and update the `LastUpdated` field of all entities marked as `EntityState.Modified`. I need to do this with MongoDB.

[This hook](https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-collection-hooks#beforeinsertuserid-doc) does it with JS but I need it in .NET

Comment: There are many ways to implement the issue. For example you could create a service to interact with the collection and encapsulate the logic to the service methods. Or it's possible to fire and handle special event each time the collection is updated. Or you could use mediator, and so on...

Comment: @Alexander do you have some code?

Comment: I have walls of code, but I think it's architectural question. So, I advise you to use [Repository pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-design#the-repository-pattern). For example, you could modify [an existing solution](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/c-sharp-mongodb-repository-implementation/)

Comment: `without changing all update calls in my code` - this quite strange feature request from db POV that also raises some questions like whether you need updating LastUpdated atomically with the main request? If no so, it's easy, look at change streams, if you need this, I don't see how to do it